# Some flex/bison questions

Tags: bison, lex

Say I have a code with has the following form.

```
display <<"hello">> (number1) (number2) (number3) {
     a = 1;
     b = 2;
     ...
}
```

Note this is only an example, albeit an ugly example, but still, it's just an exageration of what I would like to do. number1,number2,number3 are numbers, and display would be a sort of operator followed by a block between {} containing variable assignment and that would print the whole thing in a special way. As said, just an example.

My question on this is... say this syntax, the `display <<str>> ()()() {}` form is only used with the "display" keyword, and never used after. And let's say << and >> are normally operators. I wonder... how is it possible to tell bison/flex that in this case << and >> are not used as operators but only delimiters belonging to the "display" syntax? AND, how could you extract properly the data between << and >>, the numbers between () and then parsing the whole block using a DIFFERENT, SPECIFIC syntax to the block between {} ?

For example if I had :

```
display <<"hello">> (1) (5) (8) {
    a = 1;
    b = 8 * 273 + 40;
}
```

I would then like to make a call like this :

```
handle_display_operator(szStr, num1, num2, num3)

// here szStr contains "hello", num1 = 1, num2 = 5, num3 = 8
```

After this function call, I would need to parse into the block.

Could someone explain me how would I handle this properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as a bison rule like:

```
statement: DISPLAY LSHIFT string RSHIFT '(' expr ')' '(' expr ')' '(' expr ')'
                { handle_display_operator($3, $6, $9, $12); }
           block
         ;
```

where the lexer recognizes `display` as the keyword DISPLAY, and `<<` and `>>` as the tokens LSHIFT and RSHIFT.  In other contexts, (such as an expression), you'll use `LSHIFT` and `RSHIFT` as shift operators.

This allows for ANY expression in the parenthesis (which you can evaluate to an integer in your `expr` rules), and may allow string 'expressions' if you handle them in your `string` rule.

An alternative approach, if you really want raw text between the `<<`/`>>` (rather than a string), is to use a flex exclusive state for after the `display` keyword.  Then you'd have flex rules like:

```
%x display, raw_text
%{
    /* use a dynamic buffer if you don't have an upper limit on the length */
    static char raw_text_buffer[MAX_LENGTH], *raw_text_end;
%}

%%

"display"      { BEGIN(display); return DISPLAY; }
<display>"<<"  { BEGIN(raw_text); raw_text_end = raw_text_buffer; }
<raw_text>.    { *raw_text_end++ = *yytext; /* DANGER -- may overflow */ }
<raw_text>\n   { error??  or just put it in the buffer... }
<raw_text>">>" { *raw_text_end = 0;
                 yylval.string = strdup(raw_text_buffer);
                 BEGIN(INITIAL);
                 return RAW_TEXT; }
```

Now your rule will look like:

```
statement: DISPLAY RAW_TEXT '(' expr ')' '(' expr ')' '(' expr ')'
                { handle_display_operator($2, $4, $7, $10); }
           block
```

This allows inputs like `display <<  %" ,> >> (1)(2)(3)` and will pass your handle function the string `%" ,>` (including leading/trailing spaces, quotes and all.

Of course, you should add checks for buffer overflow with appropriate error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and fast answer Chris. I would still like to benefit from your experience regarding a point. In the block handled by display, say I would like to have a unique syntax inside it. Say I have a second operator called for example 'struct' which would accept also a block such as struct { block }, and that the block inside the struct syntax also has an unique syntax inside it. Again I am exagerating the example, but I'd like to clearly grasp the concept. Would I have to make another yyparse() (prefixed), or could I do it in a single parser? Thanks!